# How can I get custom type with reflect?

Tags: go, reflection, types

The following data types are defined:

```
type Status int
type RealStatus Status
```

Is there a way to get from `RealStatus` type to `Status` type with reflection?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you can still only get out an `interface{}` value from reflection, to use it as `Status`, you'll need a type assertion. Given that, you could just use a simple type conversion in the first place. What do you want to solve?

Comment: No, it is not possible to get one type from the other. The only relationship between `RealStatus` and `Status` types at runtime is that they share the same underlying type `int`.  It is possible to convert between values of those types as shown in the answer by @icza.

Comment: @MuffinTop thanks.Your answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get one type from the other. The only relationship between `RealStatus` and `Status` types is that they share the same underlying type `int`.

It is possible to convert between values of those types as shown in the answer by @icza.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible if you mean to get a `Status` *value* from a `RealStatus` *value* using reflection; you may use [`Value.Convert()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Convert) for that, for example:

```
type Status int
type RealStatus Status

rs := RealStatus(1)

st := reflect.TypeOf(Status(0))

var i interface{}
i = reflect.ValueOf(rs).Convert(st).Interface()

fmt.Printf("%T %v", i, i)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/K1oaH3Msn3O)):

```
main.Status 1
```

Note that you can only get an `interface{}` value from reflection, so to use it as a `Status` value, you still need a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). Given that, you could just use a simple type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) in the first place, like in this example:

```
rs := RealStatus(1)

var s Status
s = Status(rs)

fmt.Printf("%T %v", s, s)
```

Which outputs the same (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xlFmYYjQDDf)), and it has the advantage that `s` has static type `Status`.